# What is a good C compiler for OSX or Windows XP or DOS?

Tags: c, macos, windows-xp, dos, pascal

What is a good C compiler for OSX or Windows XP or DOS? I would like to make a GUI shell for DOS.
Also what is a good pascal compiler for these platforms?

Comment: What are you trying to do, and why such a broad range of operating systems?

Comment: Which DOS and which version? MS-DOS 6.22? Which C? ANSI C (C99)?

Comment: I am trying to make a GUI shell for DOS. I don't know which version. Sorry to sound like an idiot, but the version within windows xp?

Comment: Thank you everyone for all you help.

Comment: @RCProgramming, DOS isn't part of Windows XP.  DOS was an operating system in itself.  Windows XP has a command line processor which looks like DOS, but it's not actually DOS.

Comment: I know. I made a mistake. I thought that Command Prompt in xp would act as dos would, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Borland's [Turbo C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_C) was very good for it's time (many happy memories of learning C with it years ago) -- it's now freely available and can be [downloaded here](http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/25636). I don't know how it compares to gcc for DOS, but it will come with an IDE if that helps...

**Edited to add...**
I've seen that you've updated that you're using XP, so you might want to look at Microsoft [Visual C++ Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Windows/) instead for something a bit more up to date. I took you literally at your word when you said DOS, and thought you were poking around with MS-DOS 6/5/4/[etc]...

Don't be put off by the C++ bit; you should still be able to do most basic C stuff with it. Just remember to build stuff as a Console App.

Comment: Thanks. I have downloaded this, but now must learn c, quite a daunting task. With my Turbo C compiler and C for Dummies Volume 1 in hand, I begin a programming journey :)

Comment: It's also very much out of date. Does it support C99? C90?

Comment: Turbo C. Serious? I wouldn't recommend it over gcc.

Comment: Note I did qualify my answer with "for it's time" and "I don't know how it compares [...]". I also don't know if the OP literally meant DOS (as in pre-Windows), so when I wrote the answer, I took him at his word :-) However he's clarified his question to state XP there's always Visual C++ Express for something more up to date (okay, it's C++, rather than C, but it does give him an IDE to do things in).

Comment: What is c99 and c90. I'd use gcc on mac though

Comment: I'd have to learn all the visual studio commands too, not just the c stuff. Also can someone help me a bit with how to use gcc

Comment: But I do like visual studio stuff- a lot.

Comment: @RCProgramming, the ISO C and ISO C++ languages are periodically updated. C99 (i.e. the 1999 edition of ISO C) is the latest version of the ISO C standard. I suspect turbo C implements C89 (the 1989 edition). This means that it may not support features which are standard in the current version of C or may have incompatible / obsolete features from the earlier version of C.

Comment: Thanks! Your reply was ery thourough

Answer (score 4):

On Mac OS X, you should use the GNU Compiler Collection (GCC). You can install it by downloading and installing the free [Xcode Developer Tools](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/xcode.html). On Windows, you can also install GCC (using [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/)).

Answer (score 2):

After a quick search you can install [`gcc`](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/) for DOS. And `gcc` is a good compiler for multiple OSs. And you can use gcc with windows through [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/). GCC is installed through Xcode on Mac OS X.

Comment: Thanks, but how do you use gcc, because I don't want to use xcode, although I have it installed. I really can't understand how to use xcode

Comment: @RCProgramming: Simplest way: Well, if your on a Mac run: `gcc FilePath/foo.c`. And if you want to make it quick just type gcc in terminal and drag-and-drop your source file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use GCC on Windows, DOS, OSX, and Linux. The issue is using it on Windows, where you will need either Cygwin (which produces executables that need cygwin environment) or MinGW. I strongly recommend MinGW along with the GNUWin32 tools.

Answer (score 1):

For the Pascal part of the question:

http://www.freepascal.org for all three OSes.

For Windows (win32/win64/wince) and OS X, consider using the http://lazarus.freepascal.org IDE/RAD

For Windows there is of course also Delphi

Answer (score 1):

Try DJGPP (GCC DOS port) or OpenWatcom for DOS.